# django-rest-framework: invalid regular expression in url_path

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a view and action defined in it:

```
class V(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
      `` some codes``
      lookup_field = 'uuid'
   
      @action(detail=True, methods=['put'], permission_classes=[IsAdminUser], url_path='approve/(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)')
      def approve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          obj = self.get_object()
          `` some codes ``
```

The app doesn't run because of:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^url/(?P[^/.]+)/approve/(?P[\w-]+)/$" is not a valid regular expression: redefinition of group name 'uuid' as group 2; was group 1 at position 46

urls.py in the app directory:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'url', views.V, basename='url')
```

The correct configuration would be like `^url/approve/(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/$`, but as the error says, it's another pattern and I don't mean it. Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: ```'^url/(?P<uuid>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$'``` ?

Comment: no, the logic I mean is [a-zA-Z0-9_] which is represented in [\w]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thr problem solved by just adding parameter `uuid` as an argument to the method.

```
def approve(self, request, uuid, *args, **kwargs):
    `blah blah blah`
```